# Magento 1 vs Magento 2 comparison on subscription purchases (recurring profile)

Tags: magento2, recurring

Do you have any experience using Magento on a subscription model (simple: make a purchase and receive the product/service in a regular basis with also regular automatic payments). We have been doing this with PayPal and/or third-party payment gateways, but somebody spread the rumor in my company (no way to know why is he telling that) that Magento 2 was “better optimized” for subscriptions models.

So, what do you think? Any hint that may point us in the right direction? Do you think is there a solid base on that statement?

Thank you.

Comment: magento 2 doesnt support recurring profiles functionality by default

Answer (score 2):

As Manashvi said, Magento 2.0 does not support recurring profiles functionality. There is no subscription functionality built in.

Magento 1 implemented subscriptions in the form of '[Recurring Profiles](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-recurring-profile.html)'. There are some annoying quirks, and payment support for them is limited (PayPal only), but there are third-party payment modules available.

At this time, to my knowledge, there are no third-party subscription modules available for Magento 2 either, so your options are effectively nonexistent, short of a custom solution. That being the case, the idea that Magento 2 is 'better optimized' for subscriptions is simply false.

---

**Update** / relevant self-promotion (April 2016): We just released an extension to bring recurring profiles-like subscriptions functionality to Magento 2. Since nothing of the sort exists out of box, you may find it of interest: [Adaptive Subscriptions for Magento2](https://store.paradoxlabs.com/magento2-subscriptions-recurring-billing.html)

Answer (score 0):

We have a couple of subscriptions modules for both versions of Magento:

- Magento 1: [Stripe Subscriptions](http://store.cryozonic.com/magento-extensions/stripe-subscriptions.html) (an add-on to [Stripe Payments](http://store.cryozonic.com/magento-extensions/stripe-payments.html))
- Magento 2: [Stripe Payments & Subscriptions](http://store.cryozonic.com/magento-2/stripe-payments-subscriptions.html) (all in one)

Answer (score -1):

I have checked [Magento 2 subscription and recurring payment](http://store.magenest.com/magento-2/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments-magento-2.html)

It is compatible with Magento 2.0.4 and some highlight features:
- The Admin can full control for subscription product.
- The customer can buy subscription or non subscription
- Manage, subpend, cancel subscription.

It seem integration with paypal now.

Comment: The link you have posed has 404ed